# Inter - thread communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, communication

If the threads are relative they share the same memory and this shared memory is a main communication between them.
If the threads are not relative they communicate sending events.
What about communication among threads from different proceses?

Answer (score 1):

Then you use [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). It doesn't matter that you do this in threads in each process, communication between processes is (by definition) always inter-process.